# Can woman tennis players participate in men's tournaments?

Tags: rules, tennis, gender

In chess it is often informally said that there are men's tournaments and women's tournaments. Actually it is not true. There are open tournaments, in which both men and women can participate. And then are tournaments for women only. This means that female chess players have a choice whether to play in the (stronger) open tournaments or in the (weaker) women's tournaments.

How is this in tennis? Can a top woman player like Swiatek choose to participate in a top men's tournament? Would Swiatek then have to go through a tough qualifying tournament?

Comment: I've removed the last bit of this otherwise interesting question as it's a bit too opinion-based for Stack Exchange - even if this is possible, it's entirely up to the organisers of each individual tournament who they give wild cards to.

Comment: A related discussion on r/tennis: [Can a woman play the ATP circuit?](https://www.reddit.com/r/tennis/comments/67ufj1/can_a_woman_play_the_atp_circuit/)

Answer (score 0):

Men cannot participate in WTA tour tournaments, but women can participate in the ATP tour.
There is no regulation in ATP that prohibits women's participation.

However, it is very hard for any woman to play at a competitive ATP-level tournanment.

Comment: Are you certain about this? I found the rules of the ATP on the internet, and they state that only men or transgender men (WTM) have the right to participate.

Comment: Do you know of any instance of a woman ever having competed in the men's tournament?